# Kettle Not Whistling

Tags: kitchen, sound

My old kettle rusted, so I bought a new one.  My old kettle whistled very loudly when the water reaches boiling point.  I can barely hear my new kettle whistle.  How can I amplify the whistling sound of my new kettle?

Comment: What brand/model is your tea kettle? Can you include a web link to the kettle?

Comment: It has a lot to do with the shape and size of the hole. If it's the wrong shape/size, you won't have much you can do, other than trying to splice on a new one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason that kettles whistle is because of the holes in a kettle spout. Kettles usually have two plates for the spout cover. Your kettle might not have one of the plates.

You can fix this with a bottle cap and some common tools. First bend the bottle cap with pliers (you can also use a hammer) so that the sides are up. Now use sandpaper to get the bottle cap round. Now drill a hole in the middle of the bottle cap. You should be able to just wedge the bottle cap in the spout cover, but if you can't, you can always use glue.

Here's some good photos showing how to build the bottle cap cover

[image] [image] [image]

Source: [Instructables](http://www.instructables.com/id/Tea-Kettle-Whistle-Repair/)

Comment: Maybe stating the obvious, but if you *are* going to glue it, make sure you use glue that can handle the temperature/moisture without melting and/or contaminating the kettle.